# Combining Unknown number of Observables in RxJava

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, concurrency, rx-java

I have a situation where I have to create *N* `Observable` objects based on a request. I understand that I can use `zip` to combine a KNOWN number of Observables. But, I'm stuck trying to understand how I can combine an unknown number of Observable.

The part where I'm not clear is what function to pass to `zip`. Depending on the number of Observables, I have to create a lambda that takes *N* arguments.

All the Observable return different types of objects.

Comment: Please add some code, which would explain your thinking a little bit. It is very unclear what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: What are these observables and how many items do they produce? Have you looked at the `zip(Observable<Observable<T>>, FuncN)` overload?

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd. I have looked at zip. The problem with it is am not sure how many observables will be available to zip because the request determines the number of observables. If there are 3 observables, I have write a lambda that accepts 3 params, if there are N observables, then I have write a lambda with N params.. which is not maintainable and determined at runtime..

Comment: Since you don't know the number of observable you're going to create, i would recommend to use a `PublishSubject`. So whenever you create a new observable publish them with your own buffer or cache mechanism and do the operation there..

Answer (score 3):

Update:

I ended up with the normal way to solve parallel request list. 
Just use flatMap, merge, zip, any combining rx operator.

The only thing we need to do specially is to use .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) for each request. All other things, sending parallel requests or simultaneous would be arranged by rxjava perfectly.

If you want to see the effect, try following:

```
private void runMyTest() {
    List<Single<String>> singleObservableList = new ArrayList<>();
    singleObservableList.add(getSingleObservable(500, "AAA"));
    singleObservableList.add(getSingleObservable(300, "BBB"));
    singleObservableList.add(getSingleObservable(100, "CCC"));
    Single.merge(singleObservableList)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(System.out::println); }

private Single<String> getSingleObservable(long waitMilliSeconds, String name) {
    return Single
            .create((SingleOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(waitMilliSeconds);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("name = " +name+ ", waitMilliSeconds = " +waitMilliSeconds+ ", thread name = "
+Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ", id =" +Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    if(!e.isDisposed()) e.onSuccess(name);
                })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); }
```

output:

> System.out: name = CCC, waitMilliSeconds = 100, thread name =
>   RxCachedThreadScheduler-4, id =463
>
> System.out: CCC
>
> System.out: name = BBB, waitMilliSeconds = 300, thread name =
>   RxCachedThreadScheduler-3, id =462
>
> System.out: BBB
>
> System.out: name = AAA, waitMilliSeconds = 500, thread name =
>   RxCachedThreadScheduler-2, id =461
>
> System.out: AAA

// ******previous answer but not accurate*******//

Use this one; solved my problem:

[`zip(java.lang.Iterable<? extends Observable<?>> ws,FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)` method](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-rx.functions.FuncN-).

An sample:

```
public Observable<CombinedData> getCombinedObservables() {
        List<Observable> observableList = new ArrayList<>();

        observableList.add(observable1);
        observableList.add(observable2);
        observableList.add(observable3);
        observableList.add(observable4);

        return Observable.zip(observableList, new Function<Object[], CombinedData>() {
            @Override
            public CombinedData apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                return new CombinedData(...);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Observables return objects of common type, merge it and process as List:

```
class Result1 implements Result
class Result2 implements Result
class REsult3 implements Result

for(Observable o : yourObservableList)
    resultObservable.mergeWith(o) //use concat() if you need serial execution

resultObservable
    .toList()
    .doOnNext(results -> {
        //process your results (List<Result>)
    }
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: you can even pass the list of observable to merge method.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Should be `mergeWith`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when I had to do form validation on an varying quantity of EditTexts based off user selection in the app.

In my specific case, all added fields had to have content in them.

This is what worked for me in the end.

```
        val ob1 = RxTextView.textChanges(field1).skip(1)
        val ob2 = RxTextView.textChanges(field2).skip(1)
        val ob3 = RxTextView.textChanges(field3).skip(1)

        val observableList = arrayListOf<Observable<CharSequence>>()

        observableList.add(ob1)
        observableList.add(ob3)

        val formValidator = Observable.combineLatest(observableList, {
            var isValid = true
            it.forEach {
                val string = it.toString()
                if (string.isEmpty()) {
                    isValid = false
                }
            }
            return@combineLatest isValid
        })

        formValidator.subscribe { isValid ->
            if (isValid) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }
```